# Give a user role capability to create orders for clients

Tags: user-roles, theme-customizer

I have WP Theme called Traveler, the theme is for hotel booking, it has partners user role, now I have created a new user role called Broker, and want to give this user the option to book rooms for his clients but only to hotels he has been assigned to. is there a plugin that can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the plugin User Role Editor? https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Comment: I've seen it but does it support to assign a number of products to a user and he can't purchase other products?